# What is the meaning of this sentence? "How many men do you know who can connive an Indian out of clothes?"

Tags: meaning, sentence, sentence-meaning

In the third episode of Barkskins (France circa 1600s), a man wants to work for somebody but he refuses. Then he says this sentence to convince him.

"How many men do you know who can connive an Indian out of clothes?"

Does it mean "How many men do you know who can steal an Indian's clothes?"

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but I didn't find anything about "connive somebody".

Comment: Look for connive.

Comment: Everywhere I look Connive includes the careful and deceitful planning to accomplish a goal. Here it would mean one who could trick an Indian, by telling lies and giving false assurances, into willingly giving up their clothing. Here I'm pretty sure it is their own clothes and not just clothes they have nearby.